# Kotlin FileNotFoundException in URL

Tags: android, kotlin

```
 val sendlink=URL(
            "$graphlink?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret=$Clientid&access_token=$shortlived")
        return sendlink.readText()
```

ı want to make a Get Request and this is the easiest way( I have tried the `as HttpUrlConnection` it gives same error ) 
But this code give error like here :

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.instagram.com/access_token?grant_type=ig_exchange_token&client_secret={mysecret}&access_token={Token}
```

Comment: You just cut the most important part: the error message.

Comment: ı update it but its the link is it that important :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of library gives FileNotFoundException Error for the request code 401 or higher.